# How to have JQuery tagsinput use a specific input

Tags: jquery

I'm using Bootstrap 3 and trying to use taginputs.  It's a very simple aspx webform that only has one type input on the page.  So things are working but i'd like to figure out how to get the taginputs not to have to go against all the inputs on the page.

Here is the code on the aspx page

```
<input type="text" ID="txtSearch" data-role="tagsinput" />
```

When this gets rendered to the code behind looks like this

```
<input type="text" placeholder="" size="1">
<input type="text" id="txtSearch" data-role="tagsinput" style="display: none;">
```

In javascript i have the code

```
$("[id$=txtSearch]").tagsinput('items');
$('input').keyup(function (e) {
    console.log("keyup");
       });
```

So it appears that the taginputs adds the input type="text" and to access the data you have to go against the 'inputs'.  Seems like there must be a way to name the input that is added so that it would not apply to all the inputs on the page.  I have not figured out how to do that yet.. anyone have this figured out.

thanks
shannon

Comment: are you trying `$("[id$=txtSearch]").prev().keyup(e){}`  ?

Comment: on keyup i'm looking to see if the , has been keyed -  if (e.which == 188).. if it has i'm firing off some ajax code to do a database search

Answer (score 0):

can you try this one? bootstrap creates new input with `.bootstrap-tagsinput` class, so handle it:

```
$(document).on('keyup', ".bootstrap-tagsinput", function(e) {
    alert('hello');
});
```

work [example on fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/20yco/oveng0px/1/)

Comment: thanks.. but I'm not sure it will do what i'm looking for.  If i were to add a second input type of text to the page and want it to also use tagsinput, I don't think i'd have control of which element the keyup would fire on.

Comment: You are using .tagsinput() function to define which input you will use, each input will under your control, if you type right selector